# Starling(Stage3d) performance advantages for video only playback

Tags: video, starling-framework

I'm building an AIR desktop app that plays back HD video. 
Since StageVideo is not supported on AIR for desktop, I was still wondering if perhaps there were any performance advantages in using Starling(Stage3D) instead of the regular displaylist for rendering and playback of the video?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to render video directly in Stage3d. You'll have to render it using conventional display list, then capture rendered image to a BitmapData object using BitmapData.draw() method, then upload this bitmap to GPU and finally draw it using 2 triangles. And all this have to be done each frame. Obviously this will be much slower than usual rendering.

Comment: Obviously?? Have you tried? I'm guessing that with larger video(ie fullscreen on a 27" monitor) you WILL see noticeable speed improvement with Stage3D rendering

Comment: I haven't tried, but I'm pretty sure it will be slower. To obtain the frame of a video you have to use an instance of flash.media.Video class. I don't know whether it will render it's content without attaching to a stage. But even if it does, each frame you'll need to 1) draw it to a BitmapData object of the appropriate size 2) upload to GPU using Texture object and 3) draw it with Context3d.drawTriangles method. The first two actions, BitmapData.draw() and Texture.uploadFromBitmapData(), are *very* expensive, especially when the BitmapData is large.

Comment: So I doubt that you'll see any speed improvement, even on a large monitor. But I may be wrong, so the best way to get the answer is to try it yourself :)